# jQuery: attr выполняется мгновенно, не смотря на то, что задана задержка!

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пример номер 1:
Необходимо, что бы картинка сначала исчезла, потом поменялась и потом появилась.

```
function slide()
    {
        $('#index_img').fadeOut(1000).attr('src', 'img/slider/next.jpg' ).fadeIn(1000);
    }
slide();
```

Картинка меняется сразу, а не после того, как исчезнет...

Пример номер 2:
Необходимо, что бы картинка менялась каждые 5 секунд после загрузки страницы.

```
function slide()
    {
        $('#index_img').attr('src', 'img/slider/next.jpg' );
    }
setInterval(slide(), 4000);
```

Картинка меняется, но сразу же после загрузки страницы, а не через 5 секунд.

Скажите пожаулуйста, как можно с этим бороться? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1

http://jsfiddle.net/dmsY3/

```
function slide()
    {
      $('#index_img').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#index_img').attr('src', 'http://www.gandex.ru/upl/oboi/thumbs/gandex.ru-13546_88864cea9acd187bf9f72aaa4d4ccb2d.jpg' ).fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }

slide();
```

Смена картинки должна вызываться ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК картинка полностью спрячется.

Comment: Спасибо, пример номер 1 действительно заработал. А как реализовать пример номер 2?

Comment: Разобрался :)
setInterval(function(){ slide(4); }, 2000);

Comment: [Убрать скобки из setInterval](http://jsfiddle.net/dmsY3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

2

```
setTimeout(slide, 4000); //если есть скобки - то это вызов функции
```

Кандидат на самую распространенную ошибку.

Comment: Не так часто на JS программирую, в моём коде функция получает значение, просто я его убрал, когда сюда вопрос писал, что бы функция была проще. Скобки по привычке оставил, как в других языках :)
Только саму проблему это, вроде, не решает...

Comment: Подобновил.

Comment: Товарищ правильно подсказал когда вызываешь setInterval(slide(), 4000); выполняется функция slide() и через  4000мс вызывается undefined функция так как slide Ниче не возвращает, если бы написали setInterval(slide,4000) все было бы в ожуре.